# Can you rend with bludgeoning weapons?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, feats, two-weapon-fighting

Playing DnD 3.5e. On the Two weapon fighting tree is Two weapon rend. Can you rend with bludgeoning weapons? or is it just with slashing attacks. We have a guy bashing with shields and he has the prerequisites to get to it but I've never heard of rending with bludgeoning weapons

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### Yes

> If you successfully hit an opponent with both of the weapons you wield, you deal extra damage equal to 1d6 + 1½ times your Strength bonus.

<sup>(*Player’s Handbook II* pg. 84)</sup>

There are no requirements or limitations on “both of the weapons” aside from there being two of them. If bludgeoning weapons could not be used with this feat, it would say so.

The name of a feat has no bearing on how it functions. Two-Weapon Rend uses “rend” because the mechanics are similar to the [rend attack of certain monsters](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/monsters/troll.htm). So in this context it’s a reference to the mechanical term for extra damage for hitting with both weapons, *not* to the usual English-language definition of the word. But even if that weren’t the case, names serve as identifiers only—always look to the actual rules text for how things work.